# Error in first workspace compilation - Raspberry PI 3 (Jessie) Indigo

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, sorry, I am a new user but I have already worked with ROS on Raspberry pi. I tried to replicate my results with the jessie version, the installation was perfect but when try to do the catkin_make I get this error and I could not solve it

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
CMake Warning (dev) at catkin/CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:

    catkin_VERSION
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
CMake Error at /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake:2 (message):
  Invalid package manifest "/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslang/package.xml": The
  manifest contains invalid XML:

  no element found: line 1, column 0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:42 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247967/error-in-first-workspace-compilation---raspberry-pi-3-(jessie)-indigo/) by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end I solved it by reinstalling from the beginning the version of ROS Kinetic with specific instructions for Raspberry PI

[Installing ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi)

---

Originally posted by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) with karma: 90 on 2017-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0